# Crash Issue - C++ Code Design using pointers and destructors

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, reference

I have a question regarding the following code, which crashes. I am creating a local variable in testfunction() and then pushing it (variable "y") into a list. This variable has a member pointer "b" of object type Ball. As I understand, this local variable "y" is on the stack, so its' destructor will be called after testfunction() is completed. Also, as I understand, a vector "copies" an object into its' list. From what I've learned, it is best practice to delete a pointer in the destructor if one exists in its' class. So, there is "delete b" in the destructor of Example.

The issue that I am having is that the object y.b is being destroyed at the completion of testfunction(). In main(), I am able to see the value of "name" and the address of "b", but the object "b" has already been deleted. I would like to avoid this.

I think there is an issue with the design of the code/use of pointers vs references, etc. Please guide me in the right direction, I am an idiot!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Ball
{
    public:
        int a;

        Ball()
        {
            a = 0;
        }

        ~Ball()
        {
            cout << "destroyed Ball()" << endl;
        }
};

class Example
{
    public:
        string name;
        Ball* b;

        Example()
        {
            name = "";
            b = NULL;
        }

        ~Example()
        {
            cout << "destroying Example()" << endl; 
            delete b;
        }
};

void testfunction(vector<Example>& list)
{
    cout << "entered testfunction1()" << endl;

    Example y;
    y.name = "myName";
    y.b = new Ball();
    y.b->a = 5;

    cout << "y.b->a = " << y.b->a << endl;
    list.push_back(y);

    cout << "exit testfunction1()" << endl;
}

void testfunction2()
{
    cout << "entered testfunction2()" << endl;
    Example* y = new Example();
    cout << "exit testfunction2()" << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<Example> list;
    testfunction(list);
    //testfunction2();

    if(list[0].b == NULL)
        cout << "b is null" << endl;
    else
        cout << "b is not null" << endl;

    cout << list[0].name << endl;
    cout << list[0].b << endl;
    cout << "list[0].b->a = " << list[0].b->a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be more appropriate just to get rid of every pointer in this example.

Comment: hi @chris, thank you for this suggestion. i thought about this as well. if get rid of Ball* and turn it into Ball. What is the best way to check if the member Ball b exists?

Comment: Use `boost::optional` for an optional object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a copy constructor and an assignement operator for your class `Example`. 
These shall copy properly your object (creating a duplicated Ball object) when pushed back on the vector.

```
Example(const Example& a)  
{
    name = a.name;  // attention no dynamic allocation
    cout << "copy" <<endl; 
    if (a.b) {
        b = new Ball(*a.b);   // create a new duplicated Ball 
    }
    else b = NULL; 
}
```

The problem in your example is that the default copy constructor is called when you pushback the object.  It copies memberwise and so the pointer to Ball is copied, not the object pointed to.

Yet another alternative could be to replace your `Ball*`  with `shared_ptr<Ball>` (and accordingly, `new Ball` with `make_shared<Ball>()`  and the `delete b` of the object with a `b.reset()`).   The principle is that this smart pointer keeps track of the number of time the object pointed to is used, so that it will not delete it twice, but only when its no longer used anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Since `class Example` has a pointer member and it tries to own a dynamically allocated resource, it needs non-default copy operations, in other words, it needs user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.

Inside `testfunction`, when you copy `y` into `vector`, both local `y` and `y copied to the vector` point to very same `Ball` object. The local `y` is destroyed at the end of the function and `Ball` is deleted. However, that deleted `Ball` still pointed by the `y in vector`

```
void testfunction(vector<Example>& list)
{
    // ...

    Example y;
    y.name = "myName";
    y.b = new Ball();
    y.b->a = 5;

    list.push_back(y);

    // ...
} // <-- destructor for Example y is called and y.b is deleted
```

Comment: `Example` doesn't need non-default copy constructors because it has a pointer member. It may need them because it is trying to own a dynamically allocated resource. Another solution would be to not own it.

Comment: I think `has a pointer member` implies `own a dynamically allocated resource` but maybe in an implicit way. Anyway, I will improve that part and make it explicit, thank you!